# Passing token from one threadgroup to other and handling the token expiry time

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have generated the auth token in setup threadgroup and have passed the auth token to other threadgroups using setProperty and property.But the token expiry time is 30mins. How do I setup the scenario in jmeter so that this can be handled

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert setUp Thread Group to "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Add a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler which will introduce delay of, say, 29 minutes and add more loops to the Thread Group

This way each 29 minutes JMeter will request for the new token and update the property holding the token with the new value.

Also be aware of [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/), this way you will not only be able to pass objects between different threads but implement custom logic like the other thread will wait until the object is present in the FIFO queue.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post. But if I have to pass my token value to the threadgroups. If I convert setUp threadgrp to normal threadgrp for the token value to be passed I have to run threadgrps consecutively which would again not simulate a real world scenario.
Can u pls suggest where I can handle token expiry time which is 30 mins. Also the token generation threadgrp is executed first and the value passed onto other threadgrps and which simulates real-world scenario